# add 2 :before's :after's on same div to create 2 triangles

Tags: html, css, pseudo-class

I have the following, where I am creating a triangle (that looks like it has a border) with css.

I want to create another triangle, exactly the same, but about 50px to the right of the 1st one.

How would you do these 2 :before's :after's ???

[JSfiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/philiplocke/nxfhy7z0/)

HTML

```
<div class="section-modules">
    <div class="my-account">
        <div class="section-module-light">
            <h3>Register Here</h3>
            <p>It’s quick and easy and you’ll be the first to know about new bits we release.</p><a href="#" class="btn btn-blank">Register Now</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.section-module-light:after, 
.section-module-light:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
}
/* Styling block element */
.my-account .section-module-light {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
    padding: 1em;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #444;
}
/* Stroke */
.my-account .section-module-light:before {
    bottom: -0px;
    left: 150px;
    border-width: 36px;
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 20px solid #ccc;
}
/* Fill */
.my-account .section-module-light:after {
    bottom: -1px;
    left: 150px;
    border-width: 34px;
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 20px solid white;
}
```

[JSfiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/philiplocke/nxfhy7z0/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you do not need to create the triangle with separate stroke and fill, use css3 transform rotate. Then you can use before for one triangle and after for the second one.

```
display: block;
width: 34px;
height: 34px;

transform: rotate(45deg);
border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
background: white;
```

see the whole code here: http://jsfiddle.net/07jfLdwL/

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS3 transform rotate properties. See documentations.